# Renting out property - individual Vs company

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, rental-property

I live in England and have a flat in Scotland that I now want to rent out. I am a higher rates tax payer. What is my best option for maximising the money I keep after tax from this rental property? There are options like registering a company to manage the property, etc. besides just simple individual income.

Please note I am aware of all the risks of renting out a property. This question is purely about maximising the amount I keep.

Comment: Do you have a mortgage on the property or is it owned outright?  Also, how much of a capital gain would there be on the property if you sold it/transferred it into a company?

Comment: @timday No mortgage. Owned outright. There would be virtually no capital gain at the moment.

Comment: The prevailing view at the moment (see websites like [Property118](https://www.property118.com/), for example) is that if you already own just one property yourself, it's generally not worth transferring it to a company.

Answer (score 0):

The company route will mean you are taxed at 19% as it's likely to be a small company rather than the higher 25% corporate tax rate, that compares to your 40% personal tax rate.  You'll have to pay accountancy fees to prepare the company acounts and file it's tax return which is likely to costs around £500 per year.

The bigger advantage is if you take out a mortgage as currently that is 100% tax deductable whilst if you keep the property as personal income only 25% is deductable.

Buy to let is still attractive as an option but only in certain circumstances.